# How is Purgeable Memory in OSX implemented?

Tags: macos, memory, kernel

I am interested in understanding the low-level implementation of Purgeable Memory in OSX (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/CachingandPurgeableMemory.html)

How does kernel indicate to the application layer that it is low on memory and some purgeable memory should be unmapped? Is this synchronous or asynchronous (i.e. does kernel just reclaim memory and application only gets to know this when it tries to access that page or does kernel requests application to release some amount of memory?)

I am from Linux background and completely new to OSX/BSD.

Answer (score 0):

> does kernel just reclaim memory and application only gets to know this
>   when it tries to access that page

Yep, this is basically it. Instead of paging out memory to a swapfile, purgeable memory pages are just dropped. Note that before accessing purgeable memory, an application needs to mark the relevant pages as non-volatile. The low-level API for this is the Mach VM API:

To allocate a block of purgeable memory, pass the `VM_FLAGS_PURGABLE` flag to `vm_allocate()`. Then use the `vm_purgable_control()` function with the `VM_PURGABLE_SET_STATE` control - this will atomically set the new purgeable state, e.g. `VM_PURGABLE_NONVOLATILE` and return the previous state (e.g. `VM_PURGABLE_EMPTY` if the kernel purged the memory).